# Kitchen Converge for windows 7 box failing with boot timeout

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I'm currently using a test kitchen to try and converge a Windows 7 machine with VMware Fusion as the provisioner to eventually deploy a chef cookbook. Every time I run a `kitchen converge` the process hangs on "Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes" and then fails due to a timeout. When I open Fusion I see the following:
[image: display of converging VM]

Does anyone know what's happening? I've been struggling for a while to get this VM converged and haven't been able to get the VM up and running successfully to the point where I can deploy my cookbooks and I'm out of ideas.

My .kitchen.yml:

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant
  ssh:
    insert_key: false
  customize:
    cpus: 2
    memory: 4096

transport:
  name: winrm

provisioner:
  name: chef_solo

platforms:
  - name: windows-7
    driver_config:
      box: opentable/win-7-professional-i386-nocm

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[my_recipe]
    attributes:
```

Comment: I can't download the box to try it right now, but the reboot thing is probably a red herring. Make sure the username and password you are using to connect via winrm is correct. You might also try updating to Vagrant 1.7.3, it has better error output when winrm can't connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that all of the VMware Windows boxes on Altas are misconfigured in one way or another. I manually built my own box (amarkon/windows-7-ult-n-x64) which now works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried finding a sane Windows 7 Vagrant box for a Puppet presentation awhile ago and ran into similar issues.  I had to run a powershell script to install Puppet before anything.  Even still, I ran into similar issues, and had to do some extra work.

I was using [the designerror box from Atlas.](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/designerror/boxes/windows-7) Perhaps my notes could assist you getting your environment up and running.  It's Puppet, but a similar (easier?) process probably is needed for Chef: https://github.com/stark525/itbestprac-pres/tree/master/vagrant

Windows 7 boxes are typically home grown and owned, so you should probably build your own box if the project warrants the commitment.  Ultimately, Windows provides a number of challenges to publicly distributable Vagrant boxes.

Comment: Yeah, we'd rather not build our own box just because this is a chef recipe we'll likely never have to use. This is a machine that is unlikely to need to be rebuilt, but we'd like to have the option just in case. Right now we're using VMware, but let me try and use virtualbox and see if we can at least get something up and running. Maybe I can convince our guys to use virtualbox instead of VMware for this recipe.